# Superimposing cost analysis for two different Azure subscriptions

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-billing-api

Subscription cost analysis is useful but is there any way we can superimpose (produce comparative graph) of two subscription for which I am the owner?

Comment: Hi Dhiraj, do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such feature provided.

You can post this feature suggestion in the [Azure Feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback). All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.